# Arrange sort WooCommerce products displayed in a specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I have 15 product categories and 50+ products into my WooCommerce website. I want to arrange (sort) products from a specific category with an array of product ids.

This is my code attempt:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'my_ordering_function', 10, 2 );
function my_ordering_function( $args ) {

    $product_category = 'engineering-service'; 

    if( ! is_product_category($product_category) ) return $args;

    $args['post__in'] = array( 181, 8622, 8689, 8832 );
    $args['orderby'] = 'post__in';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';

    return $args;
}
```

This doesn't work.

Which hooked function do I need to use?
How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right hook and the right way. Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'engineering_service_product_query', 10, 2 );
function engineering_service_product_query( $q, $query ) {
    $product_category = array('engineering-service');
    $product_ids      = array( 181, 8622, 8689, 8832 );

    if( is_product_category( $product_category ) ) {
        $q->set('post__in', $product_ids );
        $q->set('orderby', 'post__in');
        $q->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: the **$q** only showing specific products from **$product_ids** but i want to arrange them (sort) serialize.

Comment: @NoniGopal You can only sort the defined product ids in the array with this code.

Comment: opps! so how can i serialize them? can you help me?

Comment: @NoniGopal What do you mean by serialize?, I don't catch…

Comment: suppose, i have 4 products into this category. and showing the products by default sort options. i want to re-arrange the items with my choice. may i want to show the 4 number product to number 2. do you understand?

Comment: @NoniGopa This code already sort the products based on the order of the Ids in the array as `orderby` argument is `post__in`, so that allows you to sort products as you like depending on their location in the defined array of IDs, so here id 181 will come first, then 8622, then 8689 and to finish 8832.